# Is there any java built-in method to get parity of Integer?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I was working on Bit manipulation lessons. And I found the c++ built-in functions such as `__builtin_clz()`,`__builtin_popcount()`,`__builtin_parity()`.
I got all alternative java methods for set bits and trailing zeroes. For parity, I didn't find any method.

I did something like this.

```
int val = 0b100011;
System.out.println(Integer.bitCount(val)%2==0?"Even":"ODD");
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in method to get the parity of an integer.

I'm not sure what you mean by efficient, but in terms of time complexity your solution is `O(1)`.

Another [solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/finding-the-parity-of-a-number-efficiently/) is to use something like this which is also constant time complexity (taken from the link above, but also similar to the book [Hacker's Delight](https://books.google.de/books?id=VicPJYM0I5QC&lpg=PA96&ots=2o4SOStw1v&dq=hackers%20delight%20parity&hl=de&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

```
static boolean hasEvenParity(int x) 
{ 
    int y = x ^ (x >> 1); 
    y = y ^ (y >> 2); 
    y = y ^ (y >> 4); 
    y = y ^ (y >> 8); 
    y = y ^ (y >> 16); 

    // Rightmost bit of y holds the parity value 
    // if (y&1) is 1 then parity is odd else even 
    return (y & 1) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this explained anywhere why it works? Does one stop after 16 because of 32 bits maximum? I don't see this working on more than 32 bit integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to find parity as there is no built-in function to do the same. A number is said to have odd parity if it contains odd number of 1s. Otherwise it is said to have even parity.

```java
public static String findParity(int x){
     boolean isOdd = false; 
     while(x != 0) { 
         isOdd = !isOdd; 
         x= x& (x-1); 
     } 
     return (isOdd)?"odd":"even";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using a BitSet.  And you can also pass in Strings.

```java
      int v = 292229202;
      BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { v
      });
      // number of bits set to 1.
      System.out.println(bs.cardinality());

      String s = "To be or not to be that is the question.";
      BitSet bs1 = BitSet.valueOf(s.getBytes());
      System.out.println(bs1.cardinality());

      String parity = (bs1.cardinality() & 1) == 1 ? "odd" : "even";
```

And then there's the basic technique of iteration.

```java
      int sum = 0;
      for (byte b : s.getBytes()) {
         while (b != 0) {
            sum += (b & 1);
            b >>>= 1;
         }
      }
      System.out.println((sum & 1) == 1 ? "odd"
            : "even");
```

Comment: BitSet is great But It doesn't supports all the bit manipulation functions such as Shifting and rotating.

Comment: @AashishPawar  True.  But you didn't ask for that.